# Как называется элемент, который на картинке?

Tags: javascript

И так, меня интересует в нижнем углу строка. При наведение мышкой на любой элемент содержащий переход, выскакивает данная строка URL. Хочу поискать в документациях, но не знаю как называется этот объект.
[image]

Вопросы:

1. Как называется данное "чудо"?
2. Если в браузере отключено данное "чудо", как получить точно такую строку?

Output:

- Код на JS;
- new String(url);

Пробовал получить значение вот так:

[image]

Comment: Как называется, убей, не помню...))  На сколько знаю вообще нет возможности ее отключать... Ну а если ее нет, сделать проще простого, вешаешь на ссылку обработчик события mouseenter и при каждом событии  запускаешь окно и строкой можешь передать href данной ссылки

Answer (score 8):

Данный объект называется "Строка состояния" (Status bar). Он перекочевал в современные браузеры из более старых версий. И не только браузеров, но и вообще программ. Данная строка служит для того, что бы отображать краткую контекстную информацию о выбранном/используемом объекте, текущем состоянии/статусе программы или какого либо её процесса.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
*В окне текстового редактора, данная строка состояния используется для того, что бы перед глазами была всегда актуальная информация о положении курсора*

Comment: точно, статус бар))))))